# finding current location for specific time

Tags: android

i want to find my current location on google map through GPS, but the thing is that it should search current location till a specific amount of time for e.g 30 sec, and after 30 sec GPS should stop searching or GPS should stop automatically.

And then i want to save the current location point as Langitude and Longitude.
My Code is lyk that :-

```
//on create

  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {


                lmngr = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                llstnr = new MyLocationListener();


                 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                    provider = lmngr.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                    Location location = lmngr.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                    if (location != null) {

                        lmngr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,llstnr);


                      } else {

                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No location found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

            }

            else{


                 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                 alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Check Connection");
                 alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("No internet Connection Do U Want To Exit ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        Nissan_Map_Final.this.finish();
                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                alertDialog.show();

          //     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

My location listener class :-

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),(int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
        int cur_lati = (int)location.getLatitude();
        int cur_longi = (int)location.getLongitude();   
        float   accuracy = location.getAccuracy();
        String add = " ";

        p = new GeoPoint((int) (cur_lati * 1E6),(int) (cur_longi * 1E6));
        mc = mapView.getController();
        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(18);

        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {



            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                    p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

            if (addresses.size() > 0)
            {

                for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                    add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) ;

            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        cur_loc.setText("Your Accuracy: " + accuracy + "\n" + "Address is:" + location.getLatitude() + "" + location.getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lmngr.removeUpdates(llstnr);
    }



}
```

Comment: lmngr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,30,0,llstnr);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Threads which will look for location updated till your desired time. And also need to play with the variables which will keep track whether location is found or not.

Comment: but i am not familiar with THREADS, can u explain in detail plz

Comment: Sure. Thread i something which runs parallel to your main code. Try to make thread which tries to update location every second or 2 seconds. And if it finds location stop the thread. And if its does not find location after given time period do whatever stuff you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
package cz.okhelp.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimerActivity extends Activity {
TextView hTextView;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        hTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
        MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
//        public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period) 
//        Schedule a task for repeated fixed-delay execution after a specific delay.
//
//        Parameters
//        task  the task to schedule. 
//        delay  amount of time in milliseconds before first execution. 
//        period  amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions. 

        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 3000, 1500);        

    }
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
          // ERROR
         hTextView.setText("Impossible");
         // how update TextView in link below  
                 // http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-task-timertask-run-cancel-android-example/
        System.out.println("");
      }
    }


}
```

now customize your activity to reload in particular time............